# django template changed date format from queryset

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset

I created a queryset:

```
my_data = My_User.objects.filter(Q(first_name = 'John') |
                                  Q(last_name = 'Doe'))
```

now one of the fields in `my_data` has date (`type: datetime.datetime`)
format of this date field in db is yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS eg: 2013-04-01 12:50:58

but when I display this information via django template, date format changes by default!
It displays: April 1, 2013, 12:50 p.m.

code in template:

```
{% for each_user in my_data %}
<tr>
  <td>{{each_user.timestamp}}</td>
  <td>{{each_user.first_name}}</td>
  <td>{{each_user.last_name}}</td>
  <td>{{each_user.address}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I want date format as: mm-dd-yyyy HH:MM:SS AM/PM.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default date format for django template is:
`'N j, Y' (e.g. Feb. 4, 2003)`
Hence you see the different date format from the database. 
You can read more about this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-format)

You can format date using the inbuilt date filter:

```
{{each_user.timestamp|date:"%d/%m/%y %H:%M"}}
```

You can replace the `"%d/%m/%y %H:%M"` with any format that you wish.

`"%d/%m/%y %H:%M"` gives you the format `"21/11/06 16:30"`

More info: [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatefilter-date)

Comment: ok when when I try {{each_user.timestamp|date:"%d/%m/%y %H:%M"}} the output was really weird! like this: "%20/%03/%13 %12:%Mar". But I end up using {{each_user.timestamp|date:"SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT"}} and it worked for me. Thanks for the reply and the links :)

Answer (score 1):

You should just use:

```
{{each_user.timestamp|date:"m-d-Y h:i:s A"}}
```

These are in the second link of the first answer, "Built-in Django template filter to format date". Those you need are explained below:

```
m   Month, 2 digits with leading zeros.                '01' to '12'
d   Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros.     '01' to '31'
Y   Year, 4 digits.                                    '1999'
h   Hour, 12-hour format.                              '01' to '12'
i   Minutes.                                           '00' to '59'
s   Seconds, 2 digits with leading zeros.              '00' to '59'
A   'AM' or 'PM'.                                      'AM'
```

Beware though, that the data passed to the template must be objects of `datetime`. I once had problem with that because of the serializer; the values are passed as string, not `datetime`, thus unable to be parsed; I only see empty strings, not the formatted string.

The first part suggested by the accepted answer, is, however, used in `datetime.datetime.strf(p)time`; the strings with `%` are used to parse or format date. They are part of python, not of Django. If you want to format the date in views, they are useful.